# Javascript window.onload not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I wrote code that should clear form when user open page. It's working in FF but not in IE, any idea why?

```
window.onload = clearForm()

  function clearForm() 
 {  

("load event detected!");  

 };
```

Comment: This *has* to be a duplicate. It has to be. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
window.onload = clearForm()
```

***calls*** `clearForm` and then assigns its return value to `window.onload`, exactly like `x = foo();` calls `foo` and assigns the result to `x`. Remove the parens:

```
window.onload = clearForm
```

---

Separately, I would strongly recommend *not* relying on the horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9). Always supply all required semicolons:

```
window.onload = clearForm;
```

(Amusingly, you *don't* need the one at the end of your `function clearForm() { ... }`, because that's a function declaration, not a statement. It's harmless, though.)

Comment: I'd call that function statement a function expression, as [functions statements](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-statements) look like function declarations but you are able to declare them conditionally in Gecko-based browsers.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: The specification calls it a [function declaration](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13). Function declarations are very different from function expressions. They happen at different times, have a different effect on the scope they're declared in, and of course are invalid in conditional code. The fact Firefox's SpiderMonkey engine allows them (rewriting them as function expressions on the fly) is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.onload = clearForm()` to `window.onload = clearForm;` otherwise because of `()` you are assigning result of your function to `window.onload`